# SQLite Connection not working in C#

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, connection-string

I was working with C# Application that manipulates a SQLite Database , Till yesterday It was working fine, It was retrieving records,

But since last night, Connection String returns Data Source = null

Below is the Test Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace SQLiteTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //string connection_string = "Data Source=UrduDictionary";
        string connection_string = "Data Source=" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Test.sqlite";
        string query = "";
        private SQLiteConnection _connection;
        private SQLiteCommand _command;
        private SQLiteDataAdapter _adapter;
        DataSet local;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    void Make_Connection()
    {
        _connection = new SQLiteConnection(connection_string);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                 
         Make_Connection();
    }

}
```

}

Below is the image what have seen during Debug in Watch Window..

[image]
The Library I am using is  **"SQLite-1.0.66.0-setup.exe"**

I have tested with other Database created but same results, Any body can help?

Comment: try adding version. "Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;"

Comment: you're sure the file exists in "Environment.CurrentDirectory"  and you have permissions?  Have you tried _connection.Open() ? throws exception?

Comment: Yes , I have necessary Permission,Til Yesterday It was working, When I try to open, It says, "Object Reference Not Set to an Instance...."

Comment: I did that, No luck.

Comment: This is failed too to show a valid data source

Comment: just in case... var pathDB = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Test.sqlite");
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pathDB)) throw new Exception();
            var connection_string = String.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;", pathDB);

Comment: Its Working .. Thank You all.. It wont Show Data Source Name : until we open Connection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what I did:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "UrduDictionary");
    string connString = string.Format("Data Source={0}", dbPath);

    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connString))
    {
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        query.Append("SELECT * ");
        query.Append("FROM CATIGORY_TABLE ");

        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query.ToString(), conn))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",
                        dr.GetValue(0),
                        dr.GetValue(1),
                        dr.GetValue(2));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Try using Path.Combine and String.Format to improve your work with strings.

Answer (score 3):

just in case...

```
var pathDB = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Test.sqlite"); 
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pathDB)) throw new Exception(); 
var connection_string = String.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;", pathDB);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what i did for sqlite connection with C#:

- I have downloaded Sqlite binaries from [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.84.0/sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x86-2010-1.0.84.0.exe)
- then here is the code to connect with Sqlite:

```csharp
string dbConnectionString = @"Data Source=Sample.s3db;Version=3;";
try
{
    SQLiteConnection sqlite_con = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString);
    sqlite_con.Open();
    string query = "select * from test;";
    SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, sqlite_con);
    SQLiteDataReader dr = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(dr.GetString(1));
    }

    sqlite_con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

In case anyone wants to use it with Entity Framework below is the code (tested with `EntityFramework version 4.1.0.0`)

**Model and DataContext**

```csharp
namespace WpfApplication1.Model
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public Int64 Id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
    public class MySqliteContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
}

List<Model.Movie> movies = new List<Model.Movie>();
using (var context = new MySqliteContext())
    movies = context.Movies.ToList();

foreach (var movie in movies)
    MessageBox.Show(movie.name.ToString());
```

and here is the **app.config** file containing `DbProviderFactories` and `DefaultConnectionFactory`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="true" />
  </configSections>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
  </startup>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
           type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.84.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySqliteContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Sample.s3db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for well elaborated reply

Answer (score 0):

Use always the last stable version, in this case is 1.6.292