# Android - Using await inside a foreach loop C#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, foreach

When I run those code, I am supposed to see a row containing some values including the price has been added to my list. The `getpriceAsync` method is a method I have created to grab data from a specific website using `JSON` and needs to be awaited, it takes a link as a parameter. I have tried to put it out of the `foreach` loop and it worked, it stucks only when it is inside the foreach loop although it throws no errors and it is not showing me the row inside my list which should contain the `string price`. I could not place the await expression outside of the loop cause it needs the item's name as a parameter. 
Any solution to my issue please ?
Thanks..

```
    protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout);
        string price = "";
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(Class1.dpPath);
        var table = db.Table<Table>();
        foreach(var item in table)
        {
            if(item.value != "0" && item.quantity != "0")
            {
                price = await GetpriceAsync(item.name); // here is the line of the await keyword
                Class1.tableItems.Add(new TableItem(item.quantity, price, "1000"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it work if the ```if statement``` is outside the ```foreach``` loop?

Comment: Sure no, because the condition of the if statement is related with the items in the table which the foreach loop is iterating through. Plus, I have tried to remove the if statement and keep my await expression inside the foreach but also did not worked.

Comment: You are using the wrong approach to select data from the Database.

Comment: Try selecting data as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646399/sqlite-connection-not-working-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

So you are overriding a method called OnCreate. This method is, I assume, called in some external code outside your control.

The method is called OnCreate, not OnCreateAsync. So I suspect the method is called without awaiting it in the external code.

Either:
* Find an async variant of this method to override.
* Use Task.WaitAll() to call the async method without making the OnCreate method into an async method.

Comment: `getpriceasync()` is a custom external method. Can you provide with code on how to implement `Task.WaitAll()` in my case ?