# How to fix 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Data.SQLite.dll

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I have a Winforms app that I am creating that uses SQLite data base and yesterday it was working perfectly fine. I was messing with the data connection strings so I could get it working where the database would create itself in the directory the program was run from. I did so successfully but when I went back into the editor nothing is working now. Every time I run the code and try to enter into the data base I get Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Data.SQLite.dll

I have reverted the changes before I was getting the error and am still getting the error. I have no idea what is wrong. I removed all the code and the lines that seem to be causing the error are these.

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(@"C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\PAFormsApp - Copy\WinFormsPA\UserDb.db");
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(connection);
connection.Open();
```

Any suggestions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDkap.png)

Comment: There is no constructor for `SQLiteCommand` that only takes a connection as a parameter. You say this worked before? Though, that would be a compiler error, not the runtime error you are reporting so it is hard to say what is going on.

Comment: @Crowcoder No complier errors on my end. Those lines were working perfectly fine. I just commented 'SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(connection);' out and ran it and am getting the same exception so I suppose it has to be the connection string but I still am not sure what to do. This exact string worked perfectly fine before like I said and I have also changed the string to a few other things all giving the same error.

Comment: @Crowcoder There is in `System.Data.SQLite`. You mean `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite`.

Comment: @dr.null OK yes I was referring to Microsoft.Data

Comment: Move the db to shorter path like `c:\UserDb.db` or to `d:` if you have one and try.

Comment: @alexisthename The exception will have more detail and a stack trace. You don't have to guess what line is erroring, can you post all the details?

Comment: And don't hardcode the db path. Set/get it in a variable or app setting entry.

Comment: @Crowcoder I added a picture to the post of what the error looks like now

Comment: @dr.null One of the working connections strings I was using before was System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + \UserDB.db but for some reason this only worked after I made the file an executable it didnt work in the compiler so I was using a hard coded path.

Comment: I missed the connection string itself. Its not correct, See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646399/sqlite-connection-not-working-in-c-sharp) to form it correctly. Note `Data Source = ...` and maybe ` ; Version=3 ; ` params.

Comment: @dr.null Thank you. When I was changing the connection strings I must have changed it incorrectly and overlooked that bit. Just needed to add Data source to all of my strings.. Messed with this for like 2 hours!